# Data reading - csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have some datas in a .dfx file and I trying to read it as a csv with pandas. But it has some special characters which are not read by pandas. They are separators as well.[I attached one line from it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2skq5.png)

The "DC4" is being removed when I print the file. The SI is read as space, correctly. I tried some encoding (utf-8, latin1 etc), but no success.
[I attached the printed first line as well. I marked the place where the characters should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYciB.png)

My code is simple:

```
import pandas

file_log = pandas.read_csv("file_log.DFX", header=None)

print(file_log)
```

I hope I was clear and someone has an idea.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The input. LINK: drive.google.com/open?id=0BxMDhep-LHOIVGcybmsya2JVM28

The expected output:

```
88.4373 0 12.07.2014/17:05:22 38.0366  38.5179 1.3448 31.9839
30.0070 0 12.07.2014/17:14:27 38.0084  38.5091 0.0056 0.0033
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By examining the example.DFX in hex (with `xxd`), the two separators are `0x14` and `0x0f` accordingly.

Read the csv with multiple separators using python engine:

```
import pandas

sep1 = chr(0x14) # the one shows dc4
sep2 = chr(0x0f) # the one shows si
file_log = pandas.read_csv('example.DFX', header=None, sep='{}|{}'.format(sep1, sep2), engine='python')

print file_log
```

And you get:

```
         0  1                    2        3        4       5        6   7
0  88.4373  0  12.07.2014/17:05:22  38.0366  38.5179  1.3448  31.9839 NaN
1  30.0070  0  12.07.2014/17:14:27  38.0084  38.5091  0.0056   0.0033 NaN
```

It seems it has an empty column at the end. But I'm sure you can handle that.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding seems to be ASCII here. DC4 stands for "device control 4" and SI for "Shift In". These are control characters in an ASCII file and not printable. Thus you cannot see them when you issue a "print(file_log)", although it might do something depending on your terminal to view this (like \n would do a new-line).

Try typing file_log in your interpreter to get the representation of that variable and check if those special characters are included. Chances are that you'll see DC4 in the representation as '\x14' which means hexadecimal 14.
You may then further process these strings in your program by using string manipulation like replace.